# Creating div inside another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, append

```
        <div class="outer">
            <ul>
                <li> list one </li> 
                <li> list two </li>
                <li> list three </li>
                <li> list four </li> 
                <li> list five </li>
                <li> list six </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

$( ".outer-grid" ).appendTo( ".outer" );
```

How can I add a new div inside another div using javascript. There is a div named "outer" so i want to add another div named "outer-grid" inside that "outer" div. And also the entire "li" should be inside the newly created div. 
I have attached my code above for more details. If you guys can help me that must be good. thanks :)

Comment: What does `.outer-grid` look like? and can you show us what you want the result to look like? Thanks

Comment: [`.wrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: Hey Trevor, thanks for the response. The div "outer" and all the other things will be automatically generated by a plugin. So I'm searching the possibilities to add another div inside the the "outer" div. That's really it. thanks :)

Comment: And the plugin is owl carousel. I need to add another div inside the div "owl-dots".

Comment: @Ashish _"And also the entire "li" should be inside the newly created div"_

Comment: Hey Andreas, I tried that in owl carousel. But it doesn't work. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I am removing it as a duplicate. The below solution looks fine but as Andreas mention about .wrap(). You should use wrap method. I am testing for plain js method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for jquery wrap() function :
http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

You can try this :

```
$('.outer ul').wrap("<div class='outer-grid'></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you wish to go from

```
<div class="outer">
    <ul>
        <li> list one </li> 
        <li> list two </li>
        <li> list three </li>
        <li> list four </li> 
        <li> list five </li>
        <li> list six </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="outer-grid">
        <ul>
            <li> list one </li> 
            <li> list two </li>
            <li> list three </li>
            <li> list four </li> 
            <li> list five </li>
            <li> list six </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

We can do this easily; create your `.outer-grid` element, put the list inside it, and put that inside `.outer`.

```
//create the outer-grid element
let outerGrid = $('<div class="outer-grid"></div>');

//put the list in there
let list = $('ul');
outerGrid.append(list);

//put that in the outer element
$('.outer').append(outerGrid);
```

And you're done! This works, because we're simply defining a reference `list` to the list element, and moving that around. That we remove it from the DOM for a moment isn't an issue.

Comment: Why not put the class attribute in your first statement?

Comment: Like `let outerGrid = $('<div></div>').addClass('outer-grid');`? Yeah, I could do that. But that's not as readable. It doesn't matter, really.

Comment: No. `$('<div class="outer-grid"></div>')`

Comment: Good point. I personally never use that way to create elements because I'm afraid of the performance impact it has (no idea whether or not there is one though) but sure, that sounds good :)